# Axiom of Completeness for set of integers

Tags: analysis, axioms

If $A$ is a subset of the integers $\mathbb{Z}$, and is bounded above, then A has a supremum $\alpha$ that is an element of the integers $\mathbb{Z}$. Is this statement true?

Comment: Sure. Suppose $A$ is bounded above by $N$.  Then you can test each of the integers $1,2,3,\ldots, N$ and find the largest one that is a member of $A$; this is the supremum of $A$.

Comment: You can formalize the argument suggested by MJD using induction. A small care is needed, since $\mathbb Z$ itself does not satisfy induction.

Comment: (Ah, yes, as Henning points out, another detail to mind is that the result fails if $A$ is empty, of course. It holds otherwise.)

Answer (score 6):

It is **not true**. A counterexample is $A=\varnothing$, which is bounded above by $42$, but has no supremum in $\mathbb Z$.